# Apache mod_ldap / mod_authnz_ldap not caching?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-12.04, cache

I have an Ubnutu 12.04 server running Apache2 that is configured as a reverse proxy.  Apache has been further configured for basic authentication via LDAP.  Everything is working fine, except the performance is a bit laggy.  The LDAP Auth directives are:

```
    <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthName "Secure Intranet"
            AuthLDAPURL ldaps://virt-ldap.mylan.int:636/ou=MyCorp,dc=mylan,dc=int

            AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
            AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
            AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
            Require ldap-group cn=development,ou=groups,ou=MyCorp,dc=mylan,dc=int
    </Location>
```

Upon inspection, I noticed that for every request Apache is going back to my OpenLDAP server to run a search/bind for the particular user!!!  Depending on the HTML of the site behind the proxy, some requests (e.g. JIRA) can result in 10 or 15 search/bind LDAP calls over the LAN.  I know this because I am tailing the OpenLDAP log while browsing. Yikes!

According to the [Apache2 ldap documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html#cache), mod_ldap should be caching these things by default.  Thinking that perhaps the documentation was wrong, I added these directives in ldap.conf:

```
    LDAPSharedCacheSize 500000
    LDAPCacheEntries 1024
    LDAPCacheTTL 600
    LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
    LDAPOpCacheTTL 600
```

But it made no difference.

**Edit:**

Using lynx on the server to access `https://localhost/ldap-status` returned the following:

```
    LDAP Cache Information

   Cache Name                                                             Entries           Avg. Chain Len. Hits   Ins/Rem Purges Avg Purge Time
   LDAP URL Cache                                                         1 (0% ull)           1.0 282/283 100%     1/0 (none)            0ms
   ldaps://virt-ldap.mylan.int:636/ou=MyCorp,dc=mylan,dc=int (Searches)   3 (0% full)          1.0 138/154  90%     6/3 (none)            0ms
   ldaps://virt-ldap.mylan.int:636/ou=MyCorp,dc=mylan,dc=int (Compares)   3 (0% full)          1.0 138/148  93%     6/3 (none)            0ms
   ldaps://virt-ldap.mylan.int:636/ou=MyCorp,dc=mylan,dc=int (DNCompares) 0 (0% full)          0.0     0/0 100%     0/0 (none)            0ms
```

So it seems like the cache is working, though I am not sure what exactly these numbers mean.  I am still getting tons of LAN hits against the LDAP server.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

- Have you tried looking at the cache status. If so, what does it say?
- Is shared memory enabled?

Comment: Added the ldap-status info above.  Re the shared memory, how can I check if it is enabled?  How would I enable it?  FYI - running Apache 2.2.22.

Comment: Easy check would be to see if the numbers in ldap-status jump around when you refresh.

Comment: Yes, they go up when I refresh.  It must be the relationship between  Apache and the server it is reverse proxying.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Indeed it was a weird interaction between the Apache2 reverse proxy and the server configuration (at least for JIRA).  This documentation explicitly states that caching is disabled in this case:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Synchronising+Data+from+External+Directories